# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

estoy haciendo una apliacion web con flask y en una parte se sube una imagen pero al hacer el proceso me sale el error de que no tengo permisos, ya ejecuté como administrador el CMD de windows, le di permisos de la carpeta en las propiedades y aun me sigue saliendo. Alguien sabe la solución?, muestro el codigo que estoy haciendo:

consola:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\useradmin\\Documents\\python\\proyecto\\web/static/assets'
```

uploadfiles.py

```
import os
import smtplib
from flask import json, session, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

ROOT_ABSOLUTE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = ROOT_ABSOLUTE_PATH+"/static/assets"

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

class FilesPrueba():

  def __init__(self, request_file):
    self.request_file = request_file

  def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

  def uploas_images(self)
    file = self.request_file.files['files[]']
    if file and FilesPrueba.allowed_file(file.filename):
       filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
       print('filename: ', filename)
       file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER), filename)
    #.....
```

muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta poniendo `\\static\\assets` (barra inversa, duplicada)

Comment: Lo que necesita hacer es ejecutar su secuencia de comandos de Python con privilegios elevados. Consulte [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719292/8933039) y [esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930586/8933039) para hacerlo

Comment: @abulafia hola, gracias por la ayuda, pero no funcionó

Comment: @J.Rodríguez hola, ya lo puse, sale una ventana que si dese ejecutar como adinistrador, le doy click en si, pero aun me sigue saliendo `ermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`